# Infopath Form to submit data to two sharepoint lists

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

Novice in Sharepoint and looking for some advise.

we are trying to setup a infopath form with the below fields.

ReqID (Autogenerated with a workflow based on ID like Req-1 etc.),
Description,
User,
Date,
Testing,
Tester,
Date

when the user submits the form, we would like to save the information to two separate lists on sharepoint like...

List A - ReqID, Description, User, Date

List B - ReqID, Description, Testing, Tester, Date

Can someone please advise if this is doable without using any coding.

Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possible solutions:

One list:

If it is a matter of hiding clutter from selected users then: create one list for all of the fields and then create two views, one with your first set of columns and the other with the second set of columns. This has the advantage of no duplication of data, and if you need to update the Description column, it only has to be done in one place.

Two lists:

From the InfoPath form, post all of the fields to the first list and create a View that only displays what's needed for the "A" users. Create a workflow that adds a new item to list "B" with only the data needed.

Three lists:

From the InfoPath form, post all of the fields to a master list. Create a workflow that copies selected fields to List A and to List B. This has the advantage of the master list being an unchanged source of the original data for audit or tracking purposes.

Using Web Services

I believe InfoPath can call web services. This will be more like "coding", but you can write data directly to SharePoint lists using SharePoint's REST API.